# Images pulling from stylesheet and not images folder

Tags: node.js, express

So I have an application that renders images. These images are in the following location:

```
Base Directory > public > icons
```

When I load the application on my Digital Ocean App, the images are showing the standard placeholder browser image, and serve  a 304 image pointing to my stylesheet, which is also in the public folder

```
Base Directory > public > css > stylesheet
```

How is this happening? In my express backend server I am using the entire `public` folder via:

```
app.use(express.static(join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

and I am specifying to call the icons file to render the icons in particular via the following in my template:

```
img class="img" src="/icons/<%= count.icon %> "
```

It is also important to note that the app works normally when run on my local host. The app works as required in prod, but it does not render the icons.

However, the URL itself is as it is supposed to be. ie url/icons/icon1

Does anyone have an idea as to why it is trying to call the stylesheet and not the icons folder?